# 2010: ASP.NET MVC IoC/DI - Structuremap vs Ninject, etc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control

This question have been [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60793/ninject-vs-structuremap-etc) in 2008. End of 2010 now. Any changes? which of these IOC/DI frameworks are recommended for a very large project that will be maintained forever?

Features of this project includes:

1. WCF Web Services.
2. OData exposer.
3. Special Views for various mobile devices.
4. Repository pattern with POCO.
5. Entity Framework.

Project Structure:

1. Project Domain (Database, Repository)
2. Project Services (Logic)
3. Project Web (Views, Controllers, Service Endpoints, etc)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My personal preference is still [Ninject](http://www.ninject.org/).  Excellent documentation, easy to use, drop dead simple, and gets the job done.  It's our IoC of choice in all of our projects at work, and works a treat.

Side note RE something that will last forever.  Wrap your IoC up in a facade so that you can swap it out down the road (we do this with our IoC, ORM, etc. just in case we have to change a few years from now).

Comment: +1 for Ninject, I have tried and toiled with castle, unity and think ninject is the best documented which is quite important!

Comment: We'll just have to agree to disagree then.  I personally prefer to call a facade that tosses me the appropriate object vs. explicitly referencing the methods of my DI container - same reason I go through a repository instead of directly using NHibernate objects and methods - specifically, it makes swapping out things a heck of a lot easier, since I just have to change (and possibly adapt) things in a single location.

Comment: @Bob Palmer - any links to articles on how you wrap an IoC?

Comment: @Mauricio Scheffer - Why is that bad?

Comment: @Bob Palmer, @Shawn Mclean: if you call the container, you're doing service location, not inversion of control. You lose many of the decoupling benefits.

Comment: I agree with Mauricio. You don't have to wrap the container. But you should keep your business code free of referencs to the container. The only classes that have to be aware of the container are the modules defining the bindings and a very small number of factories for the objects hat have another lifecycle than the object using them. That way you can exchange the container very fast by rewriting the modules and factories for the new container.

Answer (score 0):

Personally I use [Spring.NET](http://www.springframework.net/). This framework has much other features than a simple object container that can be used for DI.

Comment: I'm hearing bad things about xml configuration and that they are prone to errors due to not being strongly typed.

Comment: @Shawn: I favor code based configuration over XML configuration, but you can always write a unit test to test your DI's configuration.